# Feed CheckedListBox from String

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

first of all - I know there are some post according to this but i dont seem to understand the "tutoruial"

Basicly what iam trying to do is to feed an Checkedlistbox with data from a string out of an MYSQL Database

The ListBox allready contains all checkable values, now i just want the string to tell the checkedlistbox which items it should check.

My string/array .. dont realy know the right definition... (example) looks as followed: "B,BE,C1E," (Drivinglicence Types)

I would realy like to share my current work on that problem, if i wouldnt have scraped everything for the 10th time now as i realy messed up my thinking.

I would highly recomand any hints pointing me a direction as i feel lost right now

Edit: oh yeah iam using c# btw

Comment: #bump no one as a idea ?:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REAL SOLUTION

as i was unsetisfied with my last "solution" i tried around a bit more and endet up using this:

```c#
MySqlCommand führerscheinstring = conn.CreateCommand();
            führerscheinstring.CommandText = "SELECT führerschein FROM bewerber WHERE id = '" + textBoxrecruitingid.Text + "'";
            string stringführerschein = führerscheinstring.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            char[] charSeparators = new char[] { ',' };
            string[] result;

            result = stringführerschein.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

            foreach (string entry in result)
            {
                if (entry == "A")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(0,true);
                }
                else if (entry == "B")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(1, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "BE")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(2, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "C1")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(3, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "C")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(4, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "C1E")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(5, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "CE")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(6, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "D1")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(7, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "D")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(8, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "D1E")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(9, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "DE")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(10, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "L")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(11, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "T")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(12, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "ADR")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(14, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "ADR Tank")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(15, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "Module vorhanden")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(16, true);
                }
                else if (entry == "Fahrerkarte vorhanden")
                {
                    checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(17, true);
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
```

assign splitter char

```
char[] charSeparators = new char[] { ',' };
```

choose what to check (17 is item id (starts at 0) true means item will be checked)

```
checkedListBoxrecruitingführerschein.SetItemChecked(17, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

"SOLUTION"

this is not really the solution to my problem, however i wanted to share my workaround.

i added every possible combination of the checkable items into an db request asking if the db entry is one of those combinations (example down in code)

```
MySqlCommand führerscheinab = conn.CreateCommand();
            führerscheinab.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM bewerber WHERE id = '" + textBoxrecruitingid.Text + "' and führerschein = 'A,B,'";
            string countab = führerscheinab.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            MySqlCommand führerscheinabe = conn.CreateCommand();
            führerscheinabe.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM bewerber WHERE id = '" + textBoxrecruitingid.Text + "' and führerschein = 'A,BE,'";
            string countabe = führerscheinabe.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            MySqlCommand führerscheinac1 = conn.CreateCommand();
            führerscheinac1.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM bewerber WHERE id = '" + textBoxrecruitingid.Text + "' and führerschein = 'A,C1,'";
            string countac1 = führerscheinac1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            MySqlCommand führerscheinac = conn.CreateCommand();
            führerscheinac.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM bewerber WHERE id = '" + textBoxrecruitingid.Text + "' and führerschein = 'A,C,'";
            string countac = führerscheinac.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            MySqlCommand führerscheinac1e = conn.CreateCommand();
            führerscheinac1e.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM bewerber WHERE id = '" + textBoxrecruitingid.Text + "' and führerschein = 'A,C1E,'";
            string countac1e = führerscheinac1e.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

everything that was left to do was to create an if sentence for every outcome, example:

```
if (countab == 1)
{
 check a and b
}
else if (countabe == 1)
{
 check a and be
}
else if ( ... and so on
```

Not quite the solution i wanted and for sure not the beste with resources in mind but yeah .. it works ^^